# How can I create a JavaScript Blackberry Widget Extention?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-widgets

In a [recent blog post announcing Blackberry Widgets](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-Developer-s-Blog/BlackBerry-Widgets-are-Here/ba-p/351085) the following was said about getting Java library functionality in a Blackberry Widget (emphasis added by me):

> **What if RIM doesn't provide me with
>   the JavaScript API I am looking for?**
>
> RIM will continue to add new
>   JavaScript APIs for BlackBerry
>   Widgets. Most will not require new
>   BlackBerry Device Software upgrades to
>   be used.  *Java developers can also
>   create their own custom JavaScript
>   BlackBerry Widget Extension to be
>   packaged with their widget.*

They also go on to describe the architecture of a packaged widget with the following diagram:

[image]

**How can I implement a "Linked JavaScript Extension" and use it in a Widget?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is in a [press release from RIM](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-Developer-s-Blog/BlackBerry-Java-Application-Development-v5-0-Beta-4-now-live/ba-p/360786) that came out yesterday.

Use the [`net.rim.device.api.script`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/script/package-summary.html) package interface.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [The official Blackberry Widgets site](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/devbetasoftware/widgetsdk.jsp) which has some links to the [documentation and API](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/categories/?userType=21&category=BlackBerry+Widgets) that you will been for developing widgets.

I've had a quick run through the demo app from their documentation and you basically write standard HTML, CSS and Javascript.  The Javascript can then call API functions, and you setup which 'features' (using/include statements) can be accessed by setting up the config.xml file.

Comment: yeah, but how to use it with Browser Field? by opening widget locally, just like in BrowserFieldDemo?

Comment: I've looked through every single document on that site. There isn't even a single mention of JS extensions.